# Need help to define a custom environment

Tags: amsmath, environments, thmtools

I want to define a custom theorem environment. I imagine it having two invisible boxes (pictured in yellow and red) where both boxes are filled with text from optional parameters and an equal sign inbetween, like this:

```
\begin{definition}{Ideal \mathcal{a}}{abelian subgroup such that \forall a \in I and r \in R : ra \in I}
```

[image]
Is it possible in LaTeX? Could someone provide me with a MWE?

Comment: Should the yellow box have a fixed size? Should the yellow box have always the same height as the red box?

Comment: @dexteritas preferrably fixed size. It would be also great if I could manually change it somewhere in the declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Description

- `\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}` of the `mdframed` package creates a `definition` environment with a box.
- `\mydefinition{left}{right}` creates colored tikz nodes with the given text
- the size of the nodes could be changed in the definition

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand{\mydefinition}[2]{%
    \hfill

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
        \node[fill=yellow, text width=30mm, align=right] (a) {\strut#1};
        \node[right=of a.north east, anchor=north west] (eq) {\strut=};
        \node[fill=red, text width=70mm, right=of eq.north east, anchor=north west] (b) {\strut#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
    \mydefinition{Ideal $oe$}{abclian subgroup such that $\forall a \in I$ and $r \in R : ra \in I$}
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
    \mydefinition{and a very long text on the left side is also possible}{abclian subgroup such that $\forall a \in I and r \in R : ra \in I$}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]